# How to completely get rid of red wiggly underlines in new Outlook 365 on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-outlook-365

When I'm writing an E-Mail some words are underlined:
[image: underlined "mit"]
My goal: I don't want any words to be underlined - no proof reading whatsoever, no matter which language is set as default.
Anyone know what other settings I have to find and turn off in order to achieve this?

What I've done so far that didn't work:
[image: options]
Turned everything off here in Outlook
[image: German rules off]
And here in the Windows 11 settings
[image: windows11 rules off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Outlook is half-baked, and in my opinion it was released
much too early.

I recommend to revert back to Classic Outlook for Windows.

This is done in registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences`
by setting the item `UseNewOutlook` to `0`.

Reference :
[Toggling out of the new Outlook for Windows preview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/toggling-out-of-the-new-outlook-for-windows-preview-ec102b39-5727-418e-ae1f-a1805434640c).

Comment: Thanks! What I did to make it work was first turn the new Outlook toggle off and then open the old Outlook app instead of the new one I used to open.